Second Largest Number in an Array

Given an array arr, return the second largest distinct element from an array. If the second largest element doesn't exist then return -1.

I tried to find the second largest element in an array. Can anyone explain where I went wrong?
int getSecondLargest(vector<int> &arr) {
    // Code Here
    int max = 0;
    int smax = 0;
    int ans = -1;
    for(int i =0; i<arr.size();i++){
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i =0;i<arr.size();i++){
        if(arr[i]<max){
            smax = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        if(arr[i]>smax && arr[i]<max){
            smax = arr[i];
        }
    }
    if(max != smax){
        return smax;
    }
    if(max == smax){
        return ans
    }
}

Here the code doesn't give any output when the array does not contain any second largest element.

You seems to assume that number are only positive or 0...

"so can anyone explain where i went wrong?" Which is your problem?

You don't seem to read the tags descriptions while picking them. Be kind to read [tag:dsa] and learn not to silly pick tags.

Sidenote: If you reach if(max == smax), wouldn't it be safe to say that you don't need to check if they are equal since you are checking if they are not equal just above?

Use  std::nth_element

The code doesn't give any output at all; there are no output statements.

@PepijnKramer he must ignore duplicates so simple nth_element is not enough.

I think problem are corner cases: negative values, vector with repeating single value, to small vector (one or zero elements). Data constraints are not defined, so it should be assumed that it can be anything,

Can anyone explain where I went wrong? -- What is a debugger?.  At some point in your programming endeavors, you must be able to debug the code that you write.  No programmer just simply writes code, finds out it doesn't produce the results, and then dors not know what to do next (except to go to StackOverflow or ask someone else to figure out the problem).

@MarekR I know, but it is the start. And that is that OP should learn to use  and build up from there.

Looks like I've disappointed a lot of people over here...Really sorry to everyone, it was my first time hence didn't knew how stack overflow works....Apologizing once, again!

@3CxEZiVlQ I didn't knew tags had description..sorry

@PaulMcKenzie thanks for this piece of advice...new to programming will surely remember this for the future!

int getSecondLargest(vector<int> &arr) {
    if(arr.size() < 2) return -1;

    int max = INT_MIN, smax = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr[i] > max) {
            smax = max;
            max = arr[i];
        } else if(arr[i] > smax && arr[i] < max) {
            smax = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return (smax == INT_MIN) ? -1 : smax;
}

Traverse the array once. If arr[i] is larger than max, update both max and smax.
If arr[i] is between smax and max, update smax.
If no second distinct largest element exists, return -1.

Since you are checking that the array has at least 2 elements, why not initialize max and smax with the value of arr[0], and then start the loop at i=1 instead?

This is the best answer and near identical to what I was going to post. My only advice would be to return INT_MIN on error instead of -1. Unless of course OP's instructions stipulate only positive numbers are in the array.

Thanks, since this is my first post in this forum. i just wanted to provide a working answer. Anyways thanks for the suggestions! :D

Instead of a ready solution, I'll provide an idea for how to solve it using iterators.

Start by making two iterators (here called largest and second) point to the first two distinct elements. If not two distinct elements are found, return the end iterator.
Search through the rest of the range for elements larger than the second largest found so far and replace the appropriate iterator.

template <class It>
It getSecondLargest(It begin, It end) {
    if (begin == end) return end;  // no elements, return the end iterator
    auto largest = begin;

    // search for the first element not equal to *largest:
    do {
        ++begin;
        if (begin == end) return end;  // no such element found
    } while (*begin == *largest);

    auto second = begin;

    // swap them if necessary:
    if (*largest < *second) std::swap(second, largest);

    // see if there are other larger elements
    for (++begin; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (*second < *begin) {
            if (*largest < *begin) {  // largest yet?
                second = largest;     // second is now the previously largest
                largest = begin;      // and we've got a new largest
            } else if (*begin < *largest) {  // not a duplicate of largest?
                second = begin;       // then we've got a new second largest
            }
        }
    }
    return second;
}

